# How to create a 2d database

Tags: javascript, android, ios, database, react-native

My goal is to display fare between two places. Example - if the user selects source as `Place A` and destination as `Place B` the result is `$10`. There is no logic behind calculating the fare. It's a static data. I have finite number of places that user can choose between and the corresponding fare value.

**Question**
How can I store the data in such a way that it is easily accessible. I am trying to develop a cross platform mobile app.

*Note*: The app is completely offline.

Any suggestions or solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: column 1: A, column 2: B, column 3: fare

Comment: @JaromandaX Can u pls elaborate ? Are you suggesting using arrays or using sql ?

Comment: a database has tables, and a table has columns ... those are the three columns you would need in a single table that lives in a database ... I can't be more specific, because `database` is a broad term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also have some data about the places and not only about the connections between them, I'd suggest you to use two tables - One for the places with all information about them and the other one for the fares between them.

```
Place: id, name, ...

Fare: from_place_id, to_place_id, fare
```

For the cross platform part: depends if you are using some frameworks. Maybe they provide you some abstraction over the persitence layers of the different platforms, maybe not. If you write the persistence for every platform yourself, I'd use the standard ways for the specific platform, e.g. SQLite for Android, Core Data for iOS.

**Selection of the fares:**

SQL example:

If it is important which place is the source and which the destination:

```
SELECT f.fare FROM Fare WHERE f.from_place_id = ?1 AND f.to_place_id = ?2
```

If it is not important:

```
SELECT f.fare FROM Fare WHERE (f.from_place_id = ?1 AND f.to_place_id = ?2) OR (f.from_place_id = ?2 AND f.to_place_id = ?1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in json file instead.

```
import yourData from './yourData.json';
```

and access yourData like a normal JS object